# cookies not being set after deploying on aws

Tags: node.js, amazon-ec2

i deployed node.js rest api on my aws ec2 instance. in my api i set the cookies like this :

```
const postLogIn = async (req, res) => {
  const { email, password } = req.body;
  try {
    const user = await User.login(email, password);
    const token = createToken(user._id);
    res.cookie("jwt", token, {
      httpOnly: true,
      maxAge: maxAge * 1000,
    });
    res.status(200).json({
      id: user._id,
      role: user.role,
      email: user.email,
      name: user.name,
    });
  } catch (err) {
    const errors = handleErrors(err);
    res.status(400).json({ errors });
  }
};
```

everything worked great in localhost but when i deployed the app the cookies were not being set in the browser.

[image]

as you can see the cookies are being sent.
i tried adding sameSite:none to the cookie settings and still the same .

my aws instance is using http and not https. can i even send cookies from deferent domains on http ?

Comment: Were you able to solve this issue? i m having this issue also